# Change multiple consecutive variable names

Tags: rename, stata

I am using Stata 14 and have a dataset which contains a large group of variables:

```
court_date1 court_date2 court_date3
```

I would like to change part of each variable name while keeping the number at the end:

```
court_event1 court_event2 court_event3
```

Is there a way to do so as a group using the wildcard (*)? They are numbered consecutively, but are not listed consecutively in the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rename (*date*) (*event*)
```

works with just the names you give. If that catches too much, then

```
rename (court_date*) (court_event*)
```

See `help rename groups`, including the `dryrun` option.